# An inequality on the limits

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ satisfy $f(0)=1$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=A$.For any
>   $x>0$, it holds that $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{e^x+|f(x)|}$. Prove $1 \leq A
> \leq 1+\ln 2$.

How to use the differential equation. Can anyone give a hint please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'$ is strictly positive so the maximum of $f$ is $A$ at infinity.

This gives us:
$\frac{1}{e^x+A} \leq f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{e^x+1}$ for every $x$.

Integrating, $0 \leq -\frac{1}{A}\ln(1+Ae^{-x})+\frac{1}{A}\ln(1+A) \leq f(x)-f(0) \leq \ln(2)-\ln(1+e^{-x})$.
This again holds for every $x$ so we take the limit $x \to \infty$.

I.e. $0 \leq A - 1 \leq \ln(2)$.